# How to retain the entered data in an html form after clicking submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in an html page that ends up being cleared after i click the submit button. I wanted to know how I to make the data stay in the form after clicking submit in case the user needs to fix any errors. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the html code:

```
<form id = "contactform" action = "">
<label> Name:
<input name = "firstname" type = "text" id = "firstname" maxlength = "50"/>
</label>
<label> Last Name:
<input name = "lastname" type = "text" id = "lastname" maxlength = "150" />
</label>
<label> Address: 
<input name = "address" type = "text" id = "address" maxlength = "200"/>
</label>
<label> Postcode: 
<input name = "postcode" type = "text" id = "postcode" maxlength = "50" />
</label>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" onclick = "validate()" />
<input type = "reset" value = "Clear" />
</p>
</form>
```

and here is the javascript code:

```
function validate() {


var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
var address = document.getElementById('address');
var postcode = document.getElementById('postcode');

if(firstname.value == "") {
    alert("Make sure the first name field is filled");
    return false;
    } 

if(lastname.value == "") {
        alert("Make sure the last name field is filled");
        return false;
        } 
if(address.value == "") {
        alert("Make sure the address field is filled");
        return false;
        } 
if(postcode.value == "") {
        alert("Make sure the post code field is filled");
        return false;
        }
```

Comment: Why would the user want to edit something once he has clicked on submit?

Comment: ^^ Because nobody is perfect and possibly forgot to enter their last name etc .. Subsequently not wanting to fill out his first name again??  Just a hunch ..

Comment: The forms will be cleared when page refreshes, you can use ajax, so the page won't refresh or after submit, bind server end data to your input fields.

Comment: yeah that's exactly why @Zak

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a submit handler to your form:

```
<form id="contactform" action = "" onsubmit="handleSubmit()">
  ...
</form>
```

Then in your handler validate the input. If its not valid you need to preventDefault() to stop the form from submitting. *Note: You'll have to `return true` at the end of `validate()` if nothing is wrong. I don't see that in the question.*

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
  if(!validate()) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add `return` with onclick `onclick="return validate()"`

```js
function validate() {


  var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
  var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
  var address = document.getElementById('address');
  var postcode = document.getElementById('postcode');

  if (firstname.value == "") {
    alert("Make sure the first name field is filled");
    return false;
  }

  if (lastname.value == "") {
    alert("Make sure the last name field is filled");
    return false;
  }
  if (address.value == "") {
    alert("Make sure the address field is filled");
    return false;
  }
  if (postcode.value == "") {
    alert("Make sure the post code field is filled");
    return false;
  }
  }
```

```html
<form id="contactform" action="">
  <label> Name:
<input name = "firstname" type = "text" id = "firstname" maxlength = "50"/>
</label>
  <label> Last Name:
<input name = "lastname" type = "text" id = "lastname" maxlength = "150" />
</label>
  <label> Address: 
<input name = "address" type = "text" id = "address" maxlength = "200"/>
</label>
  <label> Postcode: 
<input name = "postcode" type = "text" id = "postcode" maxlength = "50" />
</label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validate()" />
  <input type="reset" value="Clear" />

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: you re welcome @rajzaveri5 .My answer is useful [mark it as a answer](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwif_KTAjKvUAhXMtY8KHZFLCY4QFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fsomeone-answers&usg=AFQjCNHZ4IpbyGACPNwGrF1LYJUvBvZJGw&sig2=hPdlhiSZ2L321-uLvjDX3A).Its more useful for future visitors